# Is there an R function for creating multiple rows based on cumulative counts?

Tags: data-structures

My data structure is typically to have one row of data for each event/individual/day. (I am usually performing survival analysis). Example spreadsheet:

[spreadsheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7MQI.png)

Pop Temp    Day Status

SIGA    515 11  1

SIGA    515 14  2

SIGA    515 14  2

SIGA    515 14  2

SIGA    515 14  2

SIGA    515 14  2

SIGA    515 14  2

I would prefer to enter my data as cumulative counts, like this:

[spreadsheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb3AZ.png)

Pop   Temp  Day Status  Count

SIGA    515 11  1   1

SIGA    515 14  2   5

Can I manipulate this structure in R, to use the "count" column as a multiplier and create a new spreadsheet with the appropriate number of individual rows for the day/status?